# Change APNS alert title with custom title

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to change the alert title received from remote notification to custom alert title and shown the custom title to the user? I have tried on silent notification but if the server provided the alert title then it will be shown to the user no matter what.

Comment: Please show what have you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO, it is not possible to change the alert title received from remote notification. You cannot run your code when your app is completely closed. so you can't customize title of APNs alert.

Tell your server guy to send appropriate title in below payload while sending APNs

> {"aps":{"alert":"Your alert title","badge":1,"sound":"default"}}

Comment: I thought about this too.

Comment: you may customize only when your app is in active state in didReceiveRemoteNotification, but it does matter because you can see there is no alert by iOS while app is active.

Answer (score 0):

If your App is in background then you can not customize as you don't have control over it, but if your App is in foreground then you can customize your App in the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method in some way.

Comment: You mean by customizing in didReceiveRemoteNotification is by popup an alert to the user? The notification tray will still show the server alert title instead of my custom title, right?

Comment: Yes, you can manage the title to show in the App in foreground, but notification dropdown which comes when App is in back ground can not be changed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a silent push which will call your application delegate's `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method. In this method you can then post a local notification with whatever content you like. The only thing to be aware of is that if your app has been killed (ie it is no longer suspended in the background) then the content of the push will be shown without launching your app.

If you use PushKit then your app will be relaunched if necessary, allowing you to customise the local notification in all cases,mbut I am not sure if you are permitted to us PushKit in non-VoIP apps

Comment: I have tried the silent push and what you mention about not receiving the notification when app is killed really concern me so I have to find other way to do it.

Comment: As I said, PushKit is the only way, but Apple any reject your app if it is not a VoIP app

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion with the PushKit. Will look into it if nothing else work.